# SQL search multitable and contains

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose that i have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Class` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `class name` CHAR(55) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
REPLACE INTO `Class` (`id`,`class name`) VALUES
    (1,'Mammalia'),(2, 'Amphibia'),(3, 'Aves'),(4, 'Reptile');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Animals` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `class_id` INT DEFAULT NULL,
     `name` CHAR(55) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `Class`(`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `Animals` (`class_id`,`name`) VALUES
    (1,'Przewalskis horse'),
    (1,'Bos taurus'),
    (1,'Sus scrofa'),
    (1,'Panthera leo'),
    (1,'Felis catus'),
    (1,'Canis lupus'),
    (1,'Pan troglodytes'),
    (1,'Nasalis larvatus'),
    (1,'Ailuropoda melanoleuca'),
    (1,'Elephas maximus sumatranus'),
    (1,'Panthera pardus orientalis'),
    (2, 'Bufu Bufu'),
    (2, 'Notophthalmus viridescens'),
    (2, 'Dermophis mexicanus'),
    (3, 'Campephilus melanoleucos melanoleucos'),
    (3, 'Tyto alba'),
    (3, 'Cathartes aura'),
    (3, 'Serinus canaria'),
    (3, 'Amazona aestiva'),
    (3, 'Amazona Oratrix'),
    (3, 'Anodorhynchus hyacinthinus'),
    (3, 'Ara ararauna'),
    (3, 'Ara chloropterus'),
    (3, 'Strigops habroptilus'),
    (4, 'Ameivula venetacaudus'),
    (4, 'Chelonia mydas'),
    (4, 'Caretta caretta');
```

I want to do a query with only one input html field that return the following results:

if i type: "Amphibia" returns:

```
-------------------
| Class | Animals |
-------------------
| Amphibia | Bufu Bufu |
| Amphibia | Notophthalmus viridescens |
| Amphibia | Dermophis mexicanus |
----------------------------------
```

if i type: "Amphibia Amazona" returns:

```
-------------------
| Class | Animals |
-------------------
| Amphibia | Bufu Bufu |
| Amphibia | Notophthalmus viridescens |
| Amphibia | Dermophis mexicanus |
| Aves | Amazona aestiva |
| Aves | Amazona Oratrix |
--------------------------
```

if i type: "caudu" returns

```
-------------------
| Class | Animals |
-------------------
| Reptile | Ameivula venetacaudus |
--------------------------
```

Sample codes in Fiddle are welcome!
Thankful right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that *input_var* is the variable that you will receive from your HTML, you can do the following query:

```
SELECT `class name`, name 
FROM Animals
LEFT JOIN Class
ON (Class.id= Animals.class_id)
WHERE `class name` like concat('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_var, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),'%')
OR name like concat('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_var, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),'%')
OR `class name` like concat('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_var, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),'%')
OR name like concat('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_var, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),'%')
;
```

I am also considering that you can receive an input with the inversed animal/class order, like "Amazona Amphibia" instead of "Amphibia Amazona".

If may also consider if *case sensitive* is important to you. If not, you may use *upper* in both your input string and the table column.

Comment: You had given a "Complete Answer".

Answer (score 1):

Keep this as your base.

```
select id, `class name`, `name` 
 from animals
 left join class
   on (class.id= animals.class_id)
```

And for searching

```
select `class name`, `name` from 
   (select ...)
   where concat("%", "$search1", "%") like `class name` or
         concat("%", "$search2", "%") like `name`;
```

To split the first word (mysql)

```
substring_index(substring_index(var, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)
```

and for second word (mysql)

```
substring_index(substring_index(var, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
```

In PHP you can use substr function.

Comment: wow, it's a good way but fault in second condition, when $search = "Amphibia Amazona".

Comment: Do not use = sign. Use like. Have those two words (if two) in two different variables. Instead you shall split from single variable using substring_index to find position of space and split

Comment: Any way to do that in SQL like this?   `Col` in (STRING_SPLIT('Amphibia Amazona', ' '))